# Extracting a 3D derived coord to its own cube

Tags: python-iris

I have loaded some data on a hybrid-p grid with iris which looks like this:

```
specific_humidity / (1)             (atmosphere_hybrid_sigma_pressure_coordinate: 48; latitude: 160; longitude: 320)
     Dimension coordinates:
          atmosphere_hybrid_sigma_pressure_coordinate                           x             -               -
          latitude                                                              -             x               -
          longitude                                                             -             -               x
     Auxiliary coordinates:
          vertical coordinate formula term: a(k)                                x             -               -
          vertical coordinate formula term: b(k)                                x             -               -
          vertical pressure                                                     x             -               -
          surface_air_pressure                                                  -             x               x
     Derived coordinates:
          air_pressure                                                          x             x               x
     Scalar coordinates:
          time: 2005-11-01 00:00:00
          vertical coordinate formula term: reference pressure: 101325.0 Pa
     Attributes:
          Conventions: CF-1.4
```

What I want is to turn the pressure coordinate into a cube for use in calculations. I can do this with the following code:

```
p_cube=humid.copy(humid.coord('air_pressure').points)
p_cube.rename('air_pressure')
p_cube.units=humd_1t.coord('air_pressure').units
```

But is there a neater way?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, to which I don't think there is a better solution to the one you've already provided.

From a design perspective, Iris' coordinates aren't quite cubes (with things like their own coordinates, cell measures & methods, etc.). It seems that really in order to do such a thing properly Iris would need to gain the concept of a Dataset (where multiple phenomena share a single set of coordinates).

The only slightly neater approach (untested) might be to do:

```
p_cube=humid.copy(humid.coord('air_pressure').points)
p_cube.metadata = humid.coord('air_pressure').metadata
```

Though I'm not 100% sure if it is valid to provide a CoordMetadata object when defining the cube's metadata.

HTH